# Extra space between code view and outline view in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not able to remove the extra space between the code view and outline view (as highlighted in red). Could someone please help me with this?

[Eclipse View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEL9w.png)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason is that you have detached the outline .To reset it to default, you can click on windows in the navbar  :
**Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective.**

Comment: It still did not work.

Comment: @skapoor03 there ?

Comment: As I had commented before, the Reset Perspective did not work for me. I still getting the same view as in the attached image.